# Find files newer than another file within each subdirectory

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

I have a folder structure like this

```
/Class/Student/Unit/files
```

Each Unit folder contains a file `MarkSheet*` that I update when I mark a students work.

I need a script that tests if the student has uploaded files newer than when I last marked their work.

The following is as close as I have been able to get (which doesn't work).

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d -name '*' -execdir \
find "{}" -type f -newer "{}"/MarkSheet* \;
```

Comment: Is the fact that the folder is Grive relevant? If not, take it out; if yes, explain what it is (apparently some Google drive client thing).

Comment: I take it that `Student` is variable and you want to do this for each `Student` folder? Why are you setting `maxdepth` and `mindepth`?

Comment: Student is a folder ie 10x3/John Smith/Unit_212/Marksheet_212_John_Smith.xls. The min/max depth ensure i get just the subdir Im interested in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for ms in Class/*/*/MarkSheet*; do
  find "${ms%/*}" -type f -newer "$ms"
done
```

With your approach, you need to a shell to expand the `MarkSheet*` glob. So:

```
find . -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d -exec sh -c '
  for dir do
    find "$dir" -type f -newer "$dir"/MarkSheet*
  done' sh {} +
```

Comment: Thank-You I couldn't workout why it worked in a terminal but not in the script.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
find /Class/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while IFS= read -r student; do
    find "$student" -type f -newer "$student/Unit/MarkSheet"*
done
```

The first `find` looks for the student directories and the second for files neer than the corresponding MarkSheet.

You can also do it the other way around:

```
find Class/ -name 'MarkSheet*' | while IFS= read -r mark; do 
  find "$(dirname "$mark")" -newer "$mark" -type f; 
done
```

The trick here is to use `dirname` to get the name of the directory containing the `MarkSheet*` file.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention it needs to support spaces in names

Comment: @ArchNemSyS sorry, my bad, should have assumed that. Updated answer should work with spaces but Stephane's is better anyway.